# How to remove title or entire header section from popover in VizFrame

Tags: sapui5

In an Do or Die situation, do we have any possibilities to hide popover title or entire header section in VizFrame. If yes then please assist me.

[image]

SAPUI5 version: 1.96.7

Answer (score 0):

**Unethical approach**

To hide VizFrame chart popover title:

```
this.oPopOver._Popover._oCustomHeader.getContentMiddle()[0].setVisible(false);
```

To hide entire header section (title + close button):

```
this.oPopOver._Popover._oCustomHeader.setVisible(false);
```

[Ethical approach](https://answers.sap.com/questions/316366/how-can-i-remove-the-title-and-close-button-of-viz.html) but in this you will loose features like ActionItems, scrollable legendGroup and many more.

Comment: This will definitely break the application in the future when the VizFrame gets some updates. Is it a custom standalone SAPUI5 application where your organization has the control over the consumed SAPUI5 version number?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann I completely agreed with you. Could you assist how can we achieve this objective ? I didn't accepted this answer yet, I thought to keep until I get reliable solution that is why I mention 'Unethical approach' in the beginning itself.

Comment: Typically in such cases, the control (VizFrame) should be then extended, and hopefully, VizFrame provides protected APIs that the extended control can implement or override safely. If not, we can only ask for an enhancement either in [SAP Customer Influence](https://www.sap.com/germany/about/customer-involvement/influence-adopt.html) or, if the module is part of OpenUI5, create an issue in the OpenUI5 GitHub repo.